# Can we recite Al Quran during salat without following the rules lengthening a part of the verse?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

I live in Bangladesh, where we don't speak Arabic. When we recite Quranic verses in Salat, we follow some rules like lengthening a part of the verse for 4 Alif or 3 Alif or 2 or 1 Alif.

My question is: Can we recite Al Quran without following this?

There are 7 styles of reading Al Quran. So what are the styles?

Comment: What do you mean by styles of reading clearfy please.

Comment: The lenghtening of a letter is prescribed by the rules of tajweed of a single qira'a (reading). Those are necessary to follow by a reciter who know them. But they also can be "lightened".

Comment: But how much is to be maintained??

Comment: For a layman as much as he can or knows. For those who excell it there's no excuse

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, you can not recite without *lengthening* the vowels. `I guess you are talking about the **Madd**s, if I'm not wrong.`

If you are not careful about *lengthening* the vowels at the appropriate places, you'ld end up with very unexpected meanings. Say for example if you say ***Allahu AAAkbar***, if you *lengthen* the **ا** then it would come up with a devastating meaning. {Is Allah Great? questioning Allah's greatness نعوذ بلله من ذالك}

So, its a must to strictly follow these **Madd**s. And why should we not follow the **Madd**s? It makes the recitations very appealing!

---

The qira'at that you follow in your country is the qira'at of Qari Hafs al Kufi, which is the most widespread qira'at in the world. All the people from all over the world follow this qira'at. It'd be more congenial and useful for you to spend time behind learning and if possible mastering the tajweed and the tarteel of the qira'at followed in your country.